# Issue with lightning dataTable while fetching related record's field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am getting the below error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')

The code for the LWC Component and controller is shown below.

**ContactController.cls**

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
        return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,AccountId,Account.Name FROM Contact];
    }
}
```

**contactDataTable LWC Component**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Change-3">
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field = 'id'
            data ={result}
            columns={columnsList}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**js file ==>**

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track,api } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContacts';

const columns = [
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName' },
    { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName' },
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'AccountName' }
];

export default class ContactDataTable extends LightningElement {
    @api result;
    @track error;

    columnsList = columns;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.getAllContacts();
    }

    getAllContacts(){
        getContacts()
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(conRec => {
                console.log('Contact Record-->', conRec)
                conRec.AccountName = conRec.Account.Name;
            })
            this.result = data;
            window.console.log('conData', data);
            this.error = undefined
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            window.console.log('conError', error);
            this.result = undefined
        })
        
    }
}
```

The error screenshot below

[image]

**Debugger Showing Failing Line**

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's erroring out because the Account on the Contact is undefined (null). Is the Contact record linked to an Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have contact records in the system that does not have Accounts linked.

Hence there is an undefined assignment that happens in the below line

```
conRec.AccountName = conRec.Account.Name;
```

The `conRec.Account` is undefined for few records and you are trying to access **Name** property of the **undefined**.

To fix this you can use an optional chaining or a simple if statement to check for undefined.

With [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (does not work for IE though)its one line fix as shown below

```
    conRec.AccountName = conRec.Account?.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Your answer really saved my day